Wondershaper Issues Disq
We have 2 servers using tunnels for some things. Normally to limit traffic we use wondershapper. But on one server we get the following output:
Error: Specified qdisc kind is unknown.
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
Error: Failed to find specified qdisc.
Error: Failed to find specified qdisc.
Error: Failed to find specified qdisc.
Error: Parent Qdisc doesn't exists.
We have an error talking to the kernel
Error: Parent Qdisc doesn't exists.
We have an error talking to the kernel
Error: Parent Qdisc doesn't exists.
We have an error talking to the kernel
Error: Parent Qdisc doesn't exists.
We have an error talking to the kernel
Error: Parent Qdisc doesn't exists.
We have an error talking to the kernel
Waiting for DAD... Done

Tried to google and search here. No help at all. Mostly dead end threads with no response or result for years.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

SELF SOLVED: FOR ANYONE ELSE FACING THIS, THE VERSION IS DIFFERENT ON DEBIAN AND REQUIRES FLAGS, UBUNTU DID NOT:
    post-up wondershaper -a devidhere -u 100000 -d 100000

THAT IS THE WORKING CODE. THE OLD CODE WAS:
    post-up wondershaper devidhere 100000 100000

Changing it by adding flags is the solution :) I hope this helps anyone that has these issues also. There are many places when you google these errors that people have asked, but nobody ever provided a response to any of them. This should help others in the future, so I'll leave it up, regardless of it being closed by mods.

Hi, can you please add at the start of the wondershaper script the following line, then edit your question with the new output? It will help us understand what command is producing what error log: set -o xtrace

Edited original question to add solution we found. Your solution wouldn't have found the issues, but thank you for trying :)
